# How do I send data from one project (Python) to another project (Java) via HTTP?

Tags: python, postgresql, http, flask, jax-rs

The project in python scrapes the web and downloads metadata into a postgres database. Data is being grabbed from postgres using psycopg2. Basically, I need to send that data to another project - a Java application that feeds data into a NLP algorithm. I think I'm only worried about the webservice interaction here.

The python project webservice is configured with Flask, while the Java webservice is configured in RESTful.

I have my python webservice function that gets data:

```
ACCEPT_TEMPLATE = "application/some.medical.{}+json"
ACCEPT_V1 = ACCEPT_TEMPLATE.format(1)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

@accept(ACCEPT_V1)
def getDownloadedArticles():
    conn = getDbConn(logger) # getDbConn gets the db connection with psycopg2
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    query = ("SELECT * FROM articles")

    cursor.execute(query)
    article = cursor.fetchone()

    return generalDataToDict(article) # Converts to dict format
```

And here's the java webservice

```
import javax.ws.rs.Path;

/**
 * A webservice for the feeder.
 */
@Path("feeder")
public class FeederWebservice {
    
    public void processDocument() {
        # processing here
    }
```

I have very little experience with webservices and http interactions, so any guidance is appreciated!

Comment: Am I missing something here? What is the harm in making an API call from one service to another with the data? You could add the data in your request payload.

Comment: If you don’t want to communicate over a web api, you could use sockets to communicate if the programs are run on the same machine. I’m also a little confused with the question.

Comment: An API call sounds like the way to go. Would it just be a POST request with `request.args.post` with the data added? what would the url be to POST to?

Answer (score 0):

post request?

heres how u send post request on python:

```py
import requests
requests.post('URL', data=DATA)
```

Comment: someone else needs to comment the java handle code i do python not java

Comment: What would the `'URL'` be in my case?

Comment: the URL would be anything you want as long as it starts with /
then in java you would receive the request from that URL

Comment: you might have to add your IP before the / if u get an error